# Can you calculate the accuracy of a calculator?

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a phone with an inbuilt calculator. I love to play with calculators. So I did the following and the following was shown by the calculator.

When I went in the scientific tab and wrote $\pi$ it returned $3.1415926535$.

When I wrote $\pi \times 2^{32}$, it wrote $1.34930377\times10^{10}$, which basically is $1349303770$.

Now when I wrote $\frac{1349303770}{\pi\times{2^{32}}}$, it gave me $0.99999966483$.

My question is, can we predict what will my calculator give me when I write $\sqrt3 \times {2^{31}}$? Or when I write anything, can I predict what the calculator will display?

Also, what is the best method to say if a calculator is accurate or not?

According to me, first we must assume that the calculator is taking the values it is showing. Like, it should not be taking values of $\pi$ more accurate or less accurate. Secondly, I think the error must be coming due to the range of values it must be taking. But is there any logical method to determine the range of values a calculator takes?

Comment: $\pi\cdot 2^{32}$ is closer to $13493037704.5$. If you run that division, you get a bit more nines.

Answer (score 9):

The precision of a calculator is largely influenced by the number of **significant figures** used for *computation*. It is normally greater than the number of digits *displayed*.

For example, if you compute $\pi$ and it displays $3.141592654$, the *actual* number stored in its RAM might be $3.14159265\color{blue}{359}$, where the digits in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ denotes the extra figures which are not displayed.

That's the reason why you do not get $1$ from $1349303770/(2^{32} \pi)$: $1349303770$ was the *displayed* number which *you* read off from previous result, while the calculator used slightly more significant figures to *compute* $2^{32}\pi$.

There is an indirect way to count the total no. of significant figures used for *computation*:

1. Compute $\sqrt{2}$
2. Subtract $1$ from previous result (do *not* compute $\sqrt{2} - 1$ directly: you must make use of the previous result)
3. Compute $1/\text{Previous result}$. This can be tricky because the method to do this depends on the type of calculator. Again, do not type the previous answer manually.
4. Subtract $2$ from previous answer
5. Repeat Steps 3-4, until you notice a discrepancy between the fractional part of the result from Step 3 and that from Step 1
6. The approximate number of *extra* significant figures would be the total **number of subtractions** you have made before you notice a discrepancy
7. The total number of significant figures is then
   $$N = \text{no. of digits displayed} + \text{no. of extra significant figures}$$

Once this is known, you can sort of predict the result of computation by using a more precise calculator, and round off the result to $N$ figures. You might need an advanced calculator for this, such as PARI/GP.

Using my scientific calculator, these are the results:

1. $1.414213562$ (Step 1)
2. $0.414213562$ (Step 2)
3. $2.414213562$ (Step 3)
4. $0.414213562$ (Step 4)
5. $2.414213562$ (Step 3)
6. $0.414213562$ (Step 4)
7. $2.41421356\color{red}{3}$ (Step 3)
8. $0.41421356\color{red}{3}$ (Step 4)
9. $2.4142135\color{red}{59}$ (Step 3)

Hence the approximate number of *extra* significant figures would be $3$ or $4$.

**Why this method works**: each subtraction causes [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation).

Comment: Thanks. Interesting answer. +1

Comment: Nice answer!(+1)

Comment: But you did not tell about my calculator. Imagine I have the most accurate calculator. I perform my calculation above and get my answer. I also(somehow) know it's error so I can know my exact answer. Now from here how can I exactly know what the calculator would display? How can I $calculate$ the exact error my calculator gives?

Comment: Well I thought I have addressed that in the paragraph before the results of my calculator. Perhaps I didn't quite understand your question. Do you mean you want to predict what the calculator would display if you input $\sqrt{3} 2^31$? For instance my calculator would display $3719550787$, and is this what you want to predict? Or do you want to predict the result of $3719550787 / (\sqrt{3} 2^31)$ which might be $0.9999999$?

Comment: Actually, both. You see, my question is how can I exactly calculate what results will I get (or how much it would be different from the actual result, and suppose I know it). I just would like to know mainly the former, that's it.